# Ruby on Rails - old URL still exists after renaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app I didn't write, that I have to work on to change a few stuff.
One of this stuff i have to work ok, is a weird issue where we have renamed a content's title - and the URL was changed too by doing so. Yet, the resourse is now available at the old and at the new URL alike - and google sees it as duplicated content.
Is this a knows issue with Rails?

Can I fix it by redirecting the page to the new one, kind of like a 301 redirect?

Is there any code I could post to make the issue more clear, or is there any direction you can point me to?

Comment: It can be the cache that has generated a static html file. If so delete this file.

Comment: By default, the page cache directory is set to `Rails.public_path` (which is usually set to the `public` folder, or `public\share`)

Comment: mmmh there is no such folder :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem by any chance?

If you are, simply redirect the page to the new one by adding something like this to the show action in your controller:

```
...

def show
  @item = Item.find params[:id]

  if request.path != item_path(@item)
    redirect_to @item, status: :moved_permanently
  end
end

...
```

Comment: i actually am using friendly_id, let me try your solution and get back to you.

Comment: i tried this but my issue persists, the old url is still reachable

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue in your Routes File.  Check to see if the path is still there, and remove it.